# referenced node in primary tabs

Tags: routes

I am looking for a way to show a referenced node into the primary tabs menu.

I created a content type "fact box" that is referenced to an article.
Now i like to have the content type title of the fact box node in the primary tabs menu.

I tested the Quicktabs Module and References Tabs, but they don`t use the primary tabs menu.

What`s the right way to reference a node into the primary tabs menu?

Comment: So do you want to display title of referenced "factbox" node on "article" node view ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this for Drupal 7?

If so you can create a custom module using [hook_menu_local_tasks_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_local_tasks_alter/7), maybe in the hook get the arg for the nid for the current page. Then do a node load on the current pages nid to check a reference is set, then from this reference field which will contain the nid... do another node load to get its title. Finally the title local menu tab.